# How can I write lost focus and got focus property of view in view model in wpf mvvm?

Tags: c#

How to call an object from view in viewmodel class file in mvvm?

How to call the property of view in viewmodel class file in mvvm?

How can I write lost focus and got focus property of view in view model in mvvm?

I don't want to use code behind file; I want to bind view with viewmodel and using all property of view in viewmodel.

//in view model i write this
public class NetworkViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

public void AddPerson(object obj)
    {

```
if(cb_group.Text.ToUpper() == "PRIMARY")
{
    _networkList1.Add(new Person(){ FirstName = txt_fullName.Text});
}
```

}

//in view i write this

tell me how is it possible

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding about MVVM... the viewmodel should not be concerned about view-specific details like focus, mouse positions and whatever else you might want to know. If you put any of those things into your "viewmodel" it effectively becomes part of the view, then you will only have a MV-without-a-VM pattern ;)

Comment: why i cannot do this

Comment: it's not so much *"cannot"* and more *"should not"*. If you want to do something that goes against a pattern, you should really describe some of the background why you need it and what you tried. Otherwise you probably won't get a useful answer.

Comment: i want to do this plz tell me the way how is it possible for one object binding i have to make so many variables so thats why i want to do it using one object to avoid making so many variables like lostfocus,gotfocus,foreground,background etc.

Comment: i don't want to use code behind file code only viewmodel to view and view to viewmodel if necessary very less code in code behind file

Comment: Your question doesn't contain any code, so I have no idea what code you are trying to reduce.

Comment: suppose i have login form in wpf i take username and password textbox

Comment: i want to use gotfocus and lostfocus property of both username and password textbox in viewmodel class

Comment: currently i am using this gotfocus and lostfocus property in login.xaml.cs file

Comment: private void txtPassword_LostFocus(Password sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtPassword.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                txtPassword.Background = Brushes.Red;

               
            }
        }

        

        private void txtPassword_GotFocus(Password sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtPassword.Background = Brushes.White;
        }

Comment: Please edit your question with additional information / code. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: because if i make register form then i have to write so many textboxes property like this it is very lengthy process i want to do it in a single object by viewmodel plz help me

Comment: So basically, you want to show some visible feedback to the user when input validation fails?

Comment: yes but i want to do this by viewmodel not by code behind file because it is login form with two textboxes but if i do with registeration form with 30 textboxes then it is very lengthy plz tell me the short way to do this like i make an object and call it one time for all textboxes

Comment: This question has been heavily downvoted (not including me, yet). Please learn from this. It is almost certainly because the question and comments appear to have been written on a mobile phone, mostly in all-lower-case, featuring txtspk in which "please" was too much trouble to write. If you can make a good effort to **make your communications as readable as possible**, that is much appreciated by readers here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than bringing information like GotFocus and LostFocus to the viewmodel, this answer explains how to display validation results to the user.

First, the target UI element (eg. a `TextBox`) needs some `Binding` that can actually fail validation. Since you want to decide things in the viewmodel, a reasonable approach is to use the `IDataErrorInfo` interface in the viewmodel to identify errors.

In order to enable a binding to use this validation technique, set `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True`:

```
<TextBox Margin="5" Text="{Binding Text1,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The viewmodel with example validation:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public virtual string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName == "Text1")
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text1))
                {
                    return "Text is required!";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private string _Text1;
    public string Text1
    {
        get { return _Text1; }
        set { _Text1 = value; RaisePropertyChangedEvent(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent([CallerMemberName]string prop = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Now, first try this without the rest of the answer. Set the datacontext to the viewmodel and when you enter/remove anything, you should see how the validation result changes with a red border.

---

To customize the error template, you have two options: change `Validation.ErrorTemplate` and use style triggers on the `Validation.HasError` property. The following combines both approaches to display a red border on error and a light red background on error unless the control is focused:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyErrorTemplate">
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="controlWithError"/>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MyErrorTemplate}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="False"/>
                    <Condition Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCoral"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

As you see, this is an implicit style that will be applied to any textbox that doesn't have a different style applied to it.

You can customize the visual appearance in the style and/or the control template any way you want.

Comment: hi sir/mam good morning i want to use name of the tools of wpf view form in viewmodel like i take textbox name it txtUserName now i want to use this name in viewmodel plz tell me how is it possible

Comment: @gauravshukladeveloper2017 Please read about MVVM. None of your questions is even losely related to it, so you won't get any useful answers on the topic until you understand what you are talking about.

Comment: hi sir/mam gaurav shukla here plz help me exactly i want to bind the property of view in viewmodel using (Object sender,EventArgs e) is it possible because by using this we can do all working of code behind in viewmodel do something needfull plz

Answer (score 0):

You can use interactivity to do this as shown below:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"             
    d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="2500">
             
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Value}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=GotFocusValueCmd}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=LostFocusValueCmd}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>          
</StackPanel>
```